# Regular expression python[re.sub]

Tags: python, regex

Am using an same regular expression in Eclipse, Sublime and IDLE, but all three are providing different outputs.

```
Regular expression --> print(re.sub(r"a(\d{4})","A\1","a2134"))
1. Eclipse --> A.
2. Sublime --> A(SOH)
3. IDLE --> A
```

Can anyone explain why different outputs for same regular expression.

Comment: Answer Given by IDLE is correct.. 
Check online python compiler .. (If in dobt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is always providing the same string, which is -

```
'A\x01'
```

The issue is that each IDE is showing `\x01` differently. You would get similar result if you were to simply do -

```
print('A\x01')
```

This is because `'A\1'` gets converted to `'A\x01'` . If you didn't want this conversion use `r` to make the replacement a rawstring - `r"A\1"` .

For Command line Python, it shows a smiley face -

```
A☺
```